# Guidelines for transitions (slide-in from bottom/right)

Tags: ios

What's the difference between these two actions? (taken from ios 9.3)

[image: iphone_6_ios_9]

The **calendar** pushes the view from the right and the **region** pushes the view from the bottom. Are there any rules/guidelines?

Answer (score 3):

The right-to-left one is a [split-view](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/ui-views/split-views/)

> Split views are often used with filterable content; a list of filter categories appears in the primary pane, and the filtered results for the selected category are shown in the secondary pane.

The bottom-to-top one is a [scroll view](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/ui-views/scroll-views/)

> As people swipe, flick, drag, tap, and pinch, a scroll view follows the gesture, revealing or zooming content in a way that feels natural.

Also check the [navigation](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/interaction/navigation/) guidelines.

Technically, you are right, these are similar in the nature, the difference is just that second one is longer and should be scrolled vertically, so the horizontal sliding would be counter-intuitive.